# QuickTime GPS Coordinates

Tags: .net, exif, metadata-extractor

I am using the following code and am able to pull metadata without issue. However the GPS data that is associated with the file is not available. I am able to view the data when using the EXIFTool but not via the metadata extractor.

```
    Dim fullPath As String = "C:\temp\IMG_1895.MOV"
    Dim OriginalFile As New FileStream(fullPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read)
    Dim directories As IEnumerable(Of MetadataExtractor.Directory) = ImageMetadataReader.ReadMetadata(OriginalFile)

    For Each directory In directories
        For Each tag In directory.Tags
            lstPrperties.Items.Add(directory.Name & " - " & tag.Name & " = " & tag.Description)
        Next
    Next
```

Am I missing something or will this be available?

If anyone knows of another way to extract the GPS from a QuickTime (.mov) file in .NET, please advise.

[Image of the EXIFTool output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b7ago.png)

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Metadata Extractor does not yet support GPS data from QuickTime files.

The project is built largely from community contributions. If you have some time to research how to access this data, it'd be valuable. A pull request would be even better.

Answer (score 0):

GPS data from QuickTime is now supported with MetadataExtractor. (Adding this here because this question was like the first or second result on Google asking the same thing and it probably will be for other people.)

```
IReadOnlyList<MetadataExtractor.Directory> reader = MetadataExtractor.ImageMetadataReader.ReadMetadata(_File.FullName.EnsureFilePrepend());
List<MetadataExtractor.Formats.QuickTime.QuickTimeMetadataHeaderDirectory> qtDirectories = reader.OfType<MetadataExtractor.Formats.QuickTime.QuickTimeMetadataHeaderDirectory>().ToList;
string gps = qtDirectories.FirstOrDefault.GetDescription(MetadataExtractor.Formats.QuickTime.QuickTimeMetadataHeaderDirectory.TagGpsLocation);
```